# How to produce a read only iphone app like a book

Tags: iphone, database

I'm new here to stackoverflow, so bear with me. I have a book that I wrote, that I would like to have available as an iPhone app. All I want it to do is just show my content. I have done some work putting my book into excel, then into a csv format for importing into a database, so the content is all organized ok, and is in fairly accessible condition. Can someone give me a point in the right direction? From a foundational standpoint whats the best way to make my book? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drew McCormack [published a nice walkthrough](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-xxx-developing-iphone) of how he did an ebook application for the iPhone, and even provides the source code for the reader application.

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert your content into HTML, then [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) might be an easy solution.

You might also want to consider publishing as a web app, in which case you should look at [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/).

Comment: I actually found a post here on stackoverflow that talks about just importing a .txt file into a textview. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!